# How to multiply values of the dynamically created input fields in laravel+vueJs component?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.8

I'm new to vueJS+laravel and  Here is the VueJs Component under laravel5.8 
Currently, it has two buttons on selection they create dynamic input fields, I'm trying to get the multiplication of values dynamically entered by user as a total =?. please help - thanks

```
<template>
     <div><form type="get" action="/asd">
        <div>
          <label>Add A</label>
             <button type="button"  @click="addRow">100</button>
        </div>
     <div> <label>Add B</label>
         <button type="button"  @click="addRow1">200</button>
     </div>

       <div v-for="row in rows" :key="row.id">
         <button-counter :name ="row.name" :id="row.id" :value="row.value"></button-counter>
      </div>
         <div>
            <li>total = ?</li>
         </div>
      <button>submit</button>
        </form>
         </div>
</template>


<script type="text/javascript">
Vue.component("button-counter", {
    props: {
        value: {
            default: ""
        }
    },
    template: '<input name=row.name type="text" style="margin-top: 10px;" v-model="value" >'
});

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            rows: [],
            count: 0
        };
    },
    methods: {
        addRow: function() {
            var txtCount = 1;
            let id = "txt_" + txtCount;

            this.rows.push({ name:'A',value:100, description: "textbox1", id });
        },
        addRow1: function() {
            var txtCount = 1;
            let id = "txt2_" + txtCount;
            this.rows.push({name:'B',value:200, description: "textbox2", id });
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<template>
    <div><form type="get" action="/asd">
        <div>
            <label>Add A</label>
            <button type="button"  @click="addRow">100</button>
        </div>
        <div> <label>Add B</label>
            <button type="button"  @click="addRow1">200</button>
        </div>

        <div v-for="row in rows" :key="row.id">
            <button-counter :name ="row.name" :id="row.id" :value.sync="row.value"></button-counter>
        </div>
        <div>
            <li>total = {{ total }}</li>
        </div>
        <button>submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</template>


<script type="text/javascript">
    Vue.component("button-counter", {
        props: {
            value: {
                default: ""
            }
        },
        template: '<input name=row.name type="text" style="margin-top: 10px;" :value="value" @change="$emit(\'update:value\', $event.target.value)">'
    });

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                rows: [],
                count: 0
            };
        },
        computed: {
            total() {
                if (this.rows.length) {
                    return this.rows.reduce((acc, row) => acc*row.value, 1);
                }

                return 0;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            addRow: function() {
                var txtCount = 1;
                let id = "txt_" + txtCount;

                this.rows.push({ name:'A',value:100, description: "textbox1", id });
            },
            addRow1: function() {
                var txtCount = 1;
                let id = "txt2_" + txtCount;
                this.rows.push({name:'B',value:200, description: "textbox2", id });
            }
        }
    };
```

**ADDITION**

```
total(){
    return this.rows.reduce((acc, row) => acc += parseInt(row.value), 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, now I'm using for addition so changed acc*row.value to acc+row.value but it's not giving the addition of these fields, ex. if I ener 100 and 200 I get 301 and if I edit 100 to 10 I get this 10 added after 301+10 ...what else needs to be changed?

Comment: @VinodBisen I added example of **total** with addition

Comment: Above code of yours is working for the first time but if I edit any of the boxes with different value if appends instead of SUM, please help with this last issue .

Comment: @VinodBisen it's seems like row values are treated as strings you need to use **parseInt** function on them